# The entity type [type] is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am running into a strange issue with a .Net 4.8 MVC app where occasionally, both in my local development environment and in production, I receive the dreaded `The entity type <type> is not part of the model for the current context` error. Traditionally this would mean something is wrong with the context/model binding, but it only happens after some level of idle time - restarting the app pool, restarting IIS and even restarting the entire server won't solve it. Where it gets weird is if I rename the bin folder (to something like bin-old), reload the site, get an obvious error (since no bin folder exists), then rename it back, everything starts to work again and the model types that were throwing this error are suddenly fine. Note that this is a code-first implementation so no EMDX file exists, we don't use migrations, etc. Entity Framework is simply here to simplify the data access.

I don't believe it's actually a model issue (because the error will bounce around to different types with a simple refresh), so I don't know what could randomly cause this to happen but be so easily fixed as effectively re-publishing the app.

Has anyone else run into this before? Here's an example of the stack trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The entity type [type] is not part of the model for the current context.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType) +273
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +31
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +69
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalEntityEntry..ctor(InternalContext internalContext, Object entity) +158
   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Entry(TEntity entity) +124
```

Comment: Do you have a DbSet property in the context for that type? There's not really much we can do without seeing actual code.

Comment: I don't, but that's where it gets weird - it's basically all types when this happens. All I have to do is refresh the page and a new type won't be there (shown via a YSOD), so it's almost like it loses the context somehow. Renaming the bin folder, reloading the site and then renaming it back is all that corrects it, but no code changes are involved.